# Detect if overlay is in view

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

How can I detect if an overlay element is currently visible / not visible?

I think there would be a possibility to get this information over bounding boxes of the DOM-Elements, but this doesn't seem to be a good solution to me.

Is there a way to find out using the openlayers API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `ol.Overlay` position is inside `ol.View` extent with:

```
var overlay_position = overlay.getPosition();
var view_extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
console.info(ol.extent.containsCoordinate(view_extent, overlay_position));
```

Comment: Works like a charme. Thank you!